# Where to filter Shortcode string prior to execution

Tags: shortcode

Whatever WP function assembles the `$att` array from the `[myShortcode att1="..." att2="..." ...]` string uses the `"` character to delimit the data.  However, the `“` and the `”` characters seem to be read as text, not delimeters; and their use in place of `"` can lead to shortcode errors.

In theory, there shouldn't ever be a problem because `“` and `”` are not characters on the qwerty keyboard, and so would not be encountered with manual entry. Yet, cutting and pasting from sources that use `“` and `”` allow for their inclusion (and there should be error checking for that situation).  For example, the page [The Beginner’s Guide to Writing Your Own Custom Shortcode](https://torquemag.io/2017/06/custom-shortcode/) says that `[helloworld name=”Bob”]` outputs `Hello Bob!`, which is not the case because the webpage cutely styled `"` into `”`. Cutting and pasting `[helloworld name=”Bob”]` outputs `Hello ”Bob”!`;  and `[helloworld name=”Bob Smith”]` outputs `Hello ”Bob!`, since the space between `Bob` and `Smith` is read as a delimeter and the array says that `[name] = "Bob` and that `[0] = Smith`.

Doing a `preg_replace` on the shortcode string before it is parsed into the `$atts` array seems like the best way to prevent errors.  The question is where to do that.

Comment: I'd refer to the official shortcode API reference vs a random blog that has formatting issues. - https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Answer (score 0):

shortcode_atts_{$shortcode} seems to be the WordPress filter you need.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/shortcode_atts_shortcode/

It is used in the `shortcode_atts()` function:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/shortcode_atts/